# USB Modem not getting connected after resetting using usb_modeswitch

Tags: bash, usb, modem, 3g, wvdial

I have a requirement that I need to first unmount and then mount again the 3G internet modem on ubuntu 12.04 without removing it physically. The modem model is Huawei E173u. So far, I have tried this procedure:

Case 1:

step 1: I connect the modem using wvdial.
step 2: I reset using usb_modeswitch. Reset happens successfully. dmesg shows this.
step 3: I try to connect again using wvdial. wvdial exits with an error code 16 and further attemps to connect gave "modem not responding" errors.

Case 2:

step 1: I connect using wvdial.
step 2: I plug out and plug in the modem
step 3: I try to connect again using wvdial. wvdial connects successfully.

Case 3:

step 1: I connect using wvdial.
step 2: I reset using usb_modeswitch. Reset happens successfully. dmesg shows this.
step 3: I try to connect again using network manager. connects successfully.

I need the case 1 to be working. Is there something that should be done after usb_modeswitch and before trying wvdial? Am i missing something here?

Comment: Why would you remount that modem? Maybe we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: What's the exact `usb_modeswitch` command you use?

Comment: @gronostaj More Explanation: I basically get a "NO CARRIER" error with wvdial at times. And the only solution is to remove the modem and plug it back in physically and then wvdial would start to work. I however would want this to be done in a script without manual intervention. Hence usb_modeswitch.

Comment: @Dennis sudo usb_modeswitch -R -v '12d1' -p '1c05' 12d1:1c05 is the vendorID:productID from lsusb